# Wrong output by stemCompletion() function when using a corpus as dictionary

Tags: r, tm

As an example of stem completion step, suppose I want to find the most frequent (prevalent) word matched to 'univers' in c('universidad', 'university', 'university') dictionary. According to the help page of stemCompletion() function:

> type = 'prevalent' (Default) takes the most frequent match as completion.

```
library(tm) # 0.6.2
```

If I insert the dictionary as a vector:

```
stemCompletion('univers', dictionary=c('universidad', 'university', 'university'))
     univers 
"university"
```

I get the correct answer.
But if I feed the dictionary as a corpus:

```
my.dictionary <- Corpus(VectorSource(c('universidad', 'university', 'university')))
stemCompletion('univers', dictionary=my.dictionary)
      univers 
"universidad"
```

I obtain the wrong answer!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the package source `tm/src/complete.R`, it seems that if a `Corpus` is passed as the `dictionary` argument to stemComplete then that dictionary is deduped before the stem completion analysis.

The relevant lines for your version are 8-9:

```
if (inherits(dictionary, "Corpus"))
    dictionary <- unique(unlist(lapply(dictionary, words)))
```

Why the same logic is not applied to a vector dictionary is a question for the packaged maintainer but it seems that the observed behaviour is intentional.